What is the expression for a sphere whose center is shifted to x-a, z-c?
I want to construct a spherical model, in which the origin is not at $(0,0,0)$, but is offset from $x$ and $z$, like:
$(x-a)^2+y^2+(z-c)^2=r^2$, where $r >a,c$?
Is there an expression in spherical coordinates for a sphere off the center? I tried using
rn=Sqrt[(x-a)^2+y^2+(z-c)^2] and using the usual spherical coordinates, x= r Cos[ theta] Sin[ phi], y=r Sin[theta] Sin[ phi], z=r Cos[phi], where theta is the azimuthal angle, phi is the polar angle. I did not get the result I wanted.

Please add your Mathematica code, I guess you tried to plot the shifted sphere using SphericalPlot3D.

TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Spherical",   RegionMember[Sphere[{a, b, c}, r], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} -> {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}]?

Try
With[{a = 1, c = 2, r = 3}, 
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{a + r Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
r Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
c + r Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0 , Pi }, {\[Theta], 0, 
2 Pi }, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2], Mesh -> False], 
Graphics3D[Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {a, 0, c}}]]}]]


or alternative
With[{a = 1, c = 2, r = 3}, 
Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r],Axes -> True] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, z} + {a, 0, c}]


